# "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#

The full error I am receiving is:

> "The process cannot access the file 'e:\Batch\NW\data_Test\IM_0232\input\RN318301.WM' because it     is being used by another process.>>>   at IM_0232.BatchModules.BundleSort(String bundleFileName)
>      at IM_0232.BatchModules.ExecuteBatchProcess()"

The involved code can be seen below.  The `RN318301.WM` file being processed is a text file that contains information which will eventually be placed in PDF documents.  There are many documents referenced in the `RN318301.WM` text file with each one being represented by a collection of rows.  As can be seen in the code, the `RN318301.WM` text file is first parsed to determine the number of documents represented in it as well as the maximum number of lines in a documents.  This information is then used to create two-dimensional array that will contain all of the document information.  The `RN318301.WM` text file is parsed again to populate the two-dimensional array and at the same time information is collected into a dictionary that will be sorted later in the routine.

The failure occurs at the last line below:

`File.Delete(_bundlePath + Path.GetFileName(bundleFileName));`

This is a sporadic problem that occurs only rarely.  It has even been seen to occur with a particular text file with which it had not previously occurred.  That is, a particular text file will process fine but then on reprocessing the error will be triggered.

Can anyone help us to diagnose the cause of this error?  Thank you very much...

```
public void BundleSort(string bundleFileName)
    {

        Dictionary<int, string> memberDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Dictionary<int, string> sortedMemberDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        //int EOBPosition = 0;
        int EOBPosition = -1;
        int lineInEOB = 0;
        int eobCount = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;
        int maxLineCount = 0;
        string compareString;
        string EOBLine;
        //@string[][] EOBLineArray;
        string[,] EOBLineArray;

        try
        {
            _batch.TranLog_Write("\tBeginning sort of bundle " + _bundleInfo.BundleName + " to facilitate householding");

            //Read the bundle and create a dictionary of comparison strings with EOB position in the bundle being the key

            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@_bundlePath + _bundleInfo.BundleName);

            //The next section of code counts CH records as well as the maximum number of CD records in an EOB.  This information is needed for initialization of the 2-dimensional EOBLineArray array.

            while ((EOBLine = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (EOBLine.Substring(0, 2) == "CH" || EOBLine.Substring(0, 2) == "CT")
                {
                    if (lineCount == 0)
                        lineCount++;

                    if (lineCount > maxLineCount)
                    {
                        maxLineCount = lineCount;
                    }
                    eobCount++;
                    if (lineCount != 1)
                        lineCount = 0;

                }
                if (EOBLine.Substring(0, 2) == "CD")
                {
                    lineCount++;
                }
            }

            EOBLineArray = new string[eobCount, maxLineCount + 2];


            file = new StreamReader(@_bundlePath + _bundleInfo.BundleName);


                try
                {



                    while ((EOBLine = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        if (EOBLine.Substring(0, 2) == "CH")
                        {
                            EOBPosition++;
                            lineInEOB = 0;
                            compareString = EOBLine.Substring(8, 40).Trim() + EOBLine.Substring(49, 49).TrimEnd().TrimStart() + EOBLine.Substring(120, 5).TrimEnd().TrimStart();
                            memberDict.Add(EOBPosition, compareString);

                            EOBLineArray[EOBPosition, lineInEOB] = EOBLine;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (EOBLine.Substring(0, 2) == "CT")
                            {
                                EOBPosition++;
                                EOBLineArray[EOBPosition, lineInEOB] = EOBLine;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lineInEOB++;
                                EOBLineArray[EOBPosition, lineInEOB] = EOBLine;

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                _batch.TranLog_Write("\tSending original unsorted bundle to archive");
           if(!(File.Exists(_archiveDir + "\\" +DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+ Path.GetFileName(bundleFileName) + "_original")))
             {
                 File.Copy(_bundlePath + Path.GetFileName(bundleFileName), _archiveDir + "\\" +DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+ Path.GetFileName(bundleFileName) + "_original");
             }


                file.Close();
                file.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();

                File.Delete(_bundlePath + Path.GetFileName(bundleFileName));
```

Comment: Please don't dump your full code here. only provides relevant code here

Comment: I cannot see where you wrote `using`

Comment: Side note -- don't do this: `file.Close(); file.Dispose(); GC.Collect();` -- just wrap your file stream in a `using statement` to have it automatically closed and disposed.

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston is correct: your `StreamReader` instances need to be in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close/dispose your `StreamReader` first time round so the file handle is still open

Consider using the `using` construct - this will automatically dispose of the object when it goes out of scope:

```
using(var file = new StreamReader(args)) 
{
    // Do stuff
}

// file has now been disposed/closed etc
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your StreamReaders for one thing.

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@_bundlePath + _bundleInfo.BundleName);
```

You need to close the StreamReader object, and you could do this in a finally block:

```
finally {
  file.Close();
}
```

A better way is to use a using block:

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@_bundlePath + _bundleInfo.BundleName)) {
    ...
}
```

It looks to me like you are calling `GC.Collect` to try to force the closing of these StreamReaders, but that doesn't guarantee that they will be closed immediately as per the MSDN doc:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx

From that doc:
"All objects, regardless of how long they have been in memory, are **considered** for collection;"

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt responses.  I will implement using blocks and I will do so in both loops.  My apologies for putting too much code in my posting.